# .asv files in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-extension, recovery

When I save a `.m` file in a folder, MATLAB autosaves a `.asv` file in the same folder.

I opened this file and I found that it contains my code from the beginning, ignoring what I have deleted.

- What is the use of this file?
- What's the risk if I delete that file?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A .asv file is just what you said, an "AutoSave" file. It's just there so that you don't lose all your code if your computer crashes/shutdown. You can delete it whenever you want.

If you find them annoying you can go to File/Preferences/-->"Editor/Debugger" --> Autosave and turn it off.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you do not delete them from explorer, but choose to delete them when Matlab's session ends (through preferences). Autosave can be a big saver if Matlab crashes...

Comment: Or you can use git, committing every small change