# Recover unsaved files in editor after MATLAB stopped responding

Tags: matlab

I was using MATLAB and had many unsaved files in the editor.Now on compilation of one of the file,MATLAB stopped responding.I am using `ubuntu` and do not want to force close the application as I would lose all of my unsaved files.Is there any way,I can recover my unsaved files.I still have MATLAB open in the hanged state.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is a memory dump. The contents of those files have got to be in there, you might have to dig through gigabytes however... see [this answer on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/a/408929) for how to dump all writable memory of a process on linux.

Comment: Is there any chance you did not turn off the `autosave` option? If it's on, these files should be in the folder defined for auto-saving.

Comment: There should at least be temp backups of the files in the same directories. Are there any files whose names end in `~`? For instance, `foobar.m~`.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 No i did not save the files even once.So they were all untitled and no I cant find any file ending with `~`.I am looking in the folder where I normally save files,in Documents.Should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: @ItamarKatz No I did not turn it off.But I did not even save the files even once so all of them are untitled.Do you know where the autosave folder would be in ubuntu?

Comment: Maltab says that you can [save untitled files, that is, new files that you have not yet saved and are therefore untitled](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/automatically-save-backup-m-files-with-the-matlab-editor.html?nocookie=true). I'd suggest opening up a new instance of matlab and seeing what you have in the autosave preferences. Perhaps the default location will be in there. I just looked at my autosave preferences and I don't have the "Save untitled files" box checked, so it' might not be enabled by default.

Comment: I'd also guess that if it did save them, that it would be in the PWD. But you might want to check `~/.matlab` too.

Comment: No,its unchecked for me too.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 No they are not there.I think the files are gone for good now.

Comment: Sorry, man. Perhaps a core dump would be worth it. Perhaps not. Either way, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I know the questioner reached a logical conclusion to his question through the comments, I would still like to point everyone (using Windows) to a place where this question has been answered: [.asv files in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540335/asv-files-in-matlab)

A little while back I was in a similar situation where a google search landed me on this question but not on the one which I have pasted above, which would have been much more helpful and less stressful for my heart! Hope this helps others.